# How do I pass objects into an array via getters/setters across another class in PHP OOP?

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I don't understand how to pass the `InvoiceItem` objects instantiated in the `ProcessInvoice` class back to my array for output to the page.

See output at bottom of post. It *should* output all 3 items in the array and the grand invoice total.

Am I using the `$this` keyword wrong?? How to pass back the objects to the `invoiceItems` array in the `Invoice` class?

```php
    class InvoiceItem {
        private $id;
        private $itemQuanity;
        private $itemPrice;
        private $itemDescrip;

        // Getters and Setter here for above 4 attributes

        public function calculateItemTotal() {
            $total = $this->itemPrice * $this->itemQuanity;
            return $total;
        }

        public function display() {
            echo "Item ID: $this->id // Item Quanity: $this->itemQuanity // Item Price: $this->itemPrice // Item Description: $this->itemDescrip // Total: $$this->total<br>";
        }
    }
```

```php
    class Invoice {
        private $invoiceItems;

        public function __construct() {
            $item = new InvoiceItem();
            $this->invoiceItems = array($item);
        }

        public function getInvoiceItems()
        {
                return $this->invoiceItems;
        }

        public function setInvoiceItems($invoiceItems)
        {
                $this->invoiceItems = $invoiceItems;

                return $this;
        }

        public function calculateInvoice() {
            foreach ($this->invoiceItems as $item_y) {
                $invoiceTotal = $invoiceTotal += $item_y->calculateItemTotal();
            }
            echo "Invoice Total: $$invoiceTotal ";
        }

        public function displayInvoice() {
            foreach ($this->invoiceItems as $item_x) {
                $item_x->display();
            }
            return $this->calculateInvoice();
        }

    }
```

```php
    class ProcessInvoice {
        private $invoice;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->invoice = new Invoice();
        }

        public function getInvoice()
        {
                return $this->invoice;
        }

        public function setInvoice($invoice)
        {
                $this->invoice = $invoice;

                return $this;
        }

        function createInvoiceItems() {
            $item1 = new InvoiceItem();
            $item1->setId(1);
            $item1->setItemPrice(1.66);
            $item1->setItemQuanity(2);
            $item1->setItemDescrip("item example");

            $item2 = new InvoiceItem();
            $item2->setId(2);
            $item2->setItemPrice(34.99);
            $item2->setItemQuanity(1);
            $item2->setItemDescrip("bla bla");

            $item3 = new InvoiceItem();
            $item3->setId(3);
            $item3->setItemPrice(2.24);
            $item3->setItemQuanity(1);
            $item3->setItemDescrip("Another item");

            // SOMETHING WRONG HERE?!
            $this->invoice->setInvoiceItems($item1, $item2, $item3); 
        }

        function runProcess() {
            $invoice_x = new Invoice();
            $this->createInvoiceItems();
            $invoice_x->displayInvoice();
        }

    }
```

**Output:** (from a "test drive" class not in this post - Simply calls the `runProcess()` method in the `ProcessInvoice` class)

```
Item ID: // Item Quanity: // Item Price: // Item Description: // Total: $
Invoice Total: $0
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Invoice::$invoiceItems` is an array, you need to add invoices to it, you are just overwriting the property.

Create:

```
public function addInvoiceItem(InvoiceItem $invoiceItem)
{
    $this->invoiceItems[] = $invoiceItem;
    return $this;
}
```

And if you need to add several, you call the same method several times:

```
$this->invoice->addInvoiceItem($item1)
        ->addInvoiceItem($item2)
        ->addInvoiceItem($item3);
```

Additionally, your constructor doesn't appear to make a lot of sense. Why are you creating an array with an empty `InvoiceItem`?

Better just do this, and start with a properly empty array:

```
private $invoiceItems = [];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @yivi. I placed your `addInvoiceItem` function in my `Invoice` class, called that method for each item in the `ProcessInvoice` class, and removed the construct in the `Invoice` class and instead just declared a private variables as `private $invoiceItems = [];`. Does that sound right? All i'm getting for the output is `Invoice Total: $ ` on the page.

Comment: Also that's not a typo, it's so there is a dollar sign in the output

Comment: Removed the "typo" part. Remember you can "accept" an answer if it helps you solve your issue.

Comment: thanks, still working through it... still experiencing same problem as above comment